# Get complete aspx error path in ReDirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I am using asp.net (.net 3.5) app. And need an ReDirect page (Custom error for it)
E.g. If I click on following URL (and page has been moved to different URL)

http://localhost:62203/page2.aspx

On Server localhost:62203 I am using following in web.config:

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="http://localhost:53551/" mode="On">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="http://localhost:53551/"/>
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="http://localhost:53551/"/>
      </customErrors>
```

When Page2.aspx not found it gets reDirected to correct URL which is as below:

http://localhost:53551/?aspxerrorpath=/page2.aspx

Now on page http://localhost:53551/ I need to know from where the request came?
e.f. I need know the complete URL http://localhost:62203/ but with the reDirect I am getting only page name ?aspxerrorpath=/page2.aspx

Cheers
Harry

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need to write some code on `global.asax` on `Application_Error`

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Request.Path ; // get's your url
}
```

### On the error page

Get the last error, and there is the full message and the url where the error occur.

```
Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
```

Comment: oh. It mean i need to make changes in existing app to add application_error which will not be allowed. Surprising we can't get the complete URL for ReDirect

Comment: @user2739418 I have update my answer, try the GetLastError on error page that is end up.